# Component not rendering input type="radio" for all questions

Tags: reactjs, regex

I have this component, where on click user gets from API 3 questions, and each question has 4 potential answers that the user can chose from. However, once rendered, only the last question has  input type="radio".

Here is the pic

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

class QuizApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      book: '',
      questions: [],
      message: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleAnswer = this.handleAnswer.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ book: event.target.value });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const configuration = new Configuration({
      apiKey: 'APIKEY',
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

    try {
      const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: 'text-davinci-003',
        prompt: `Generate 3 quiz questions about the book "${this.state.book}" with 4 possible answers for each question"`,
        temperature: 1,
        max_tokens: 200,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
      });

      const questions = [];
      let match;
      const regex = /([^]*)\n([^]*)\n([^]*)\n([^]*)\n([^]*)\n([^]*)/g;

while ((match = regex.exec(response.data.choices[0].text))) {
  const question = {
    question: match[1],
    correctAnswer: match[2],
    wrongAnswer1: match[3],
    wrongAnswer2: match[4],
    wrongAnswer3: match[5],
  };
  questions.push(question);
}

this.setState({ questions });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({ message: 'An error occurred while generating the quiz questions' });
    }
  }

  handleAnswer(event, index) {
    const { questions } = this.state;
    const question = questions[index];

    if (event.target.value === question.correctAnswer) {
      this.setState({ message: 'Good job!' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ message: 'Wrong answer' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { book, questions, message } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Enter the name of a book:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" value={book} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button type="submit">Generate Quiz</Button>
        </Form>
        {questions.map((question, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{question.question}</p>
             <Form.Group style={{color: '#fff'}}>
      <Form.Check style={{color: '#fff'}}
        type="radio"
        label={question.correctAnswer}
        value={question.correctAnswer}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleAnswer(event, index)}
      />
      <Form.Check style={{color: '#fff'}}
        type="radio"
        label={question.wrongAnswer1}
        value={question.wrongAnswer1}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleAnswer(event, index)}
      />
      <Form.Check style={{color: '#fff'}}
        type="radio"
        label={question.wrongAnswer2}
        value={question.wrongAnswer2}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleAnswer(event, index)}
      />
      <Form.Check style={{color: '#fff'}}
        type="radio"
        label={question.wrongAnswer3}
        value={question.wrongAnswer3}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleAnswer(event, index)}
      />
    </Form.Group>
          </div>
        ))}
        {message && <p style={{color: '#fff'}}>{message}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default QuizApp;
```

Been working on this for a few hours with no luck. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: If only the last one is a radio button why are there four radio buttons in the image?

Comment: hey @DaveNewton. Thank you for your reply. Only the last question has radio buttons as it should. My problem is that two other questions from the image "Who is main protagonist" and "Who owns the twin broomstick" are missing those buttons.

EDIT: 

So what I want to have is 3 questions, with each question having 4 potential answers. Each answer is a radio button that the user can choose from. So there should be a total of 12 radio buttons.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I might format the code so people can read it more easily, and double-check that you're creating the questions the way you think you are.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you push me in the right direction?

Comment: My **guess** (can't tell, because we can't see the data you're operating on) is that you're ending up with a single `question` in the array. The **first** thing I'd do is verify that `questions` contains what you think it does at the time of render. A breakpoint or console.log is sufficient. If it's not what you expect then I'd look at the response data and the regex used to pull out the questions.

Comment: If `questions` **does** contain what you think it should (i.e., an actual list of questions) then you'll likely need to provide more information in the question, perhaps the final content of `questions` or something.